# Dioxus and Rust

Tags: web3.js, rust, react, frontend, frontendintegration

I like how Solana uses React and other popular libraries/frameworks for the front end, but I would prefer the whole project to be in Rust (WASM). Is there a way I can integrate Solana-wallet for frameworks like Dioxus (a great Wasm framework for rust)?

Comment: Does Dioxus allow you to import Javascript libraries from eg NPM and call them from your code?